# How to work with a lot (thousands) of Eloquent records in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, datatables, eloquent

I need to get all data records from a clients table, there is more than 18000 records.

I use DataTables jQuery plugin to display data, so I do not want to use paginate Laravel method here.

I just want to retrieve data and pass to DataTable jQuery. This plugin does pagination.

This is my Controller code:

```
$data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

I got 500 error, because the result is too big.

I do not want to set higher memory limit, I want to use limitations or similar.

I tried this:

```
$data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->skip(1200)->get();
```

But it only gets 10 records and no more.

Any idea?

Comment: @jszobody I've created a new question because I think the other question is wrong!

Comment: `->take(10)` is what is limiting the results to 10. If you want more, this needs to change.

Comment: @MECU, Thanks, I know that. But I need to get all data and pass to DataTables plugin, but when I tried this: $data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); I got a 500 error.

Comment: perhaps you want to read http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @Kyslik Thanks, I prefer to use a limit or similar in query, I think it's a better practice.

Comment: Make pagination and call it via ajax. take() wouldn't help you. it simply will return N of values of collection.

Comment: You should have just edited the other question to make it correct then :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use Laravel `Datatable package` which is more effective and easy to use, here is my example that How I am doing it.

> Note: I am using Yajra Datatable package for this, you all basic requirement will be cover in this.

**My Controller method, where datatable Ajax request will come**

```
public function getData()
{
    $users = User::whereHas('roles',function($q){
        $q->whereNotIn('roles.name',['user','memberstudent','educationmanager']);
    })->select(array('users.id','users.firstname','users.lastname' ,'users.username','users.email',DB::raw("'roles'"), 'users.confirmed', 'users.created_at'));        

    return Datatables::of($users)
    //->edit_column('created_at', '{{ $created_at->format("Y-m-d h:i:s") }}')
    ->edit_column('created_at', '{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime($created_at))}}')
    ->edit_column('confirmed','@if($confirmed)
        Yes
        @else
        No
        @endif')
    ->add_column('roles','{{ implode(", ", User::find($id)->roles()->lists(\'name\')) }}')
    ->add_column('actions', '
        @if(Auth::user()->hasRole("owner"))
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/users/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="iframe btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> {{{ Lang::get(\'button.edit\') }}}</a>
                <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/users/\' . $id . \'/delete\' ) }}}" class="iframe btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> {{{ Lang::get(\'button.delete\') }}}</a>
            </div>

        @elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole("superadmin") && User::find($id)->roles()->pluck(\'name\') != "owner")
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/users/\' . $id . \'/edit\' ) }}}" class="iframe btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> {{{ Lang::get(\'button.edit\') }}}</a>
                <a href="{{{ URL::to(\'admin/users/\' . $id . \'/delete\' ) }}}" class="iframe btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> {{{ Lang::get(\'button.delete\') }}}</a>
            </div>
        @endif

        ')
    ->remove_column('id')
    ->remove_column('rn') // rownum for oracle
    ->remove_column('created_at') // rownum for oracle
    ->make();
}
```

**My view is**

```
<table id="users" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">first name</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">last name</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">username</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">email</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">roles</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">activated</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**MY JS code is**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#users').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'l><'col-md-6'f>r><'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>t<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-6'p>>",
        "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSearchable": true, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 2,5 ] }
        ],
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true, //this means data will come from server, ajax based
        "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('admin/users/data') }}", // get data from this URL
        "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's great, but I tried this in laravel 4 and it doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: I have given you laravel 4 code.. Its working perfectly.. You just need to change this according to your requirement and structure.. What error you getting?

Comment: Yes, my code it's working fine, but I would like to use DataTables plugin to display records.
Now I use this:
$data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(50); It works!
If I use DataTables plugin in my view I got just 50 records
I tried this:
$data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); I got 500 error, (18000 records). 
I do not want to set limit time on the server or on my php code and my users have to wait for the request.
So I thought there was a way that I could get all data and pass to DataTables from my laravel controller. "without have to implement an ajax script".

Comment: 18000 records are not very small. It will crash your page as will as will be burden on server. Better to use pagination and limits for smooth performance

Comment: Yeah, so my question is, how to limit and pass data to DataTables plugin?
I tried this:
$data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(100)->take(100)->get(); 
I got just 100 records in my $data var, how to get all data and pass to the DataTables plugin?
Thanks! I do not have experience manage big data.

Comment: Did you installed laravel datatable package? If not then better to use this. Because through this you can easily handle the pagination. Search in Google 'Yajra datatable'

Answer (score 0):

You really, really need to use server-side pagination in this case.

The problem with relying on client-side pagination (i.e., the plugin's pagination feature) is that the response from your API containing all 18,000 records will be **humongous**, and your users will not only have to wait for the request to complete (which literally could take minutes for this much data), but depending on how the plugin works they may also have to wait while it renders the DOM for all these records.

It looks like Datatables supports [server-side pagination](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).  Why not give that a try?

Comment: I am not an expert in ajax or DataTables plugin, I've read the documentation, I uderstand that I need to implement a ajax to get data. "Much more code". Thanks!

Comment: You can still use DataTables with the paginated AJAX data source...what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, my code it's working fine, but I would like to use DataTables plugin to display records. Now I use this: $data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(50); It works! If I use DataTables plugin in my view I got just 50 records I tried this: $data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); I got 500 error, (18000 records). I do not want to set limit time on the server or on my php code and my users have to wait for the request. So I thought there was a way that I could get all data and pass to DataTables from my laravel controller. "without have to implement an ajax script".

Answer (score 0):

I have adopted another solution, using paginate method from laravel and forget  DataTables plugin, DataTables is a great plugin!, but in my case, to use this plugin, would have to implement an ajax script to get data. 
Currently I have the system implemented to work with routes, controllers, views with Teepluss themes and a search tool.

I thought there was a simpler way to implement this plugin with Laravel using MVC pattern.

With this lines I have what I need:

```
My controller
public function index()
{
$data = Client::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(50);
$theme = Theme::uses('mytheme');       
$view = array(
    'name' => 'Teepluss',
    'data' => $data,
);

return $theme->scope('clients.index', $view)->render();
}


My view
//-- Table head here

@foreach($data->getCollection()->all() as $value)
//-- Table and data here
@endforeach

//-- Pagination links
{{ $data->appends(Request::except('page'))->links() }}
```

No 500 error, get all data, pagination working fine. Of course, I am giving up other features of DataTables plugin for the moment...

Anyway thank you very much!